# thickening cream

Tags: baking

I use corn starch & 1/2 and 1/2 to make my cannoli cream. I use a double boiler. My recipe calls for a lot of stirring up to an hour in order to get the thickness I need to stuff cannoli shells. 
My question is that the mixture never comes to a boil, so what am I doing wrong? & is it necessary to stir for so long?
I look forward to your answer.
thank you
Joann

Comment: Please edit your question to include the filling recipe you're following. (Note: The actual recipe, not a link to it.)

Comment: If it's not boiling, you probably don't have the stove hot enough. Also, stiring cools down food since exposing a higher surface area to the air.

Comment: @Bee The stuff is in a double boiler, meaning it's not going to come to a boil regardless of how high the burner is set.

Comment: Why? If I were you I'd start with heavy cream and merely boil/simmer/reduce it till it's thick enough. It wouldn't taste so starchy..

Comment: In my experience, cannoli is usually filled with a ricotta based "cream"/filling.  Sharing your recipe would be helpful.

Comment: @Sneftel whatever the recipe is, that's probably the answer to her question right there.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the exact recipe, it is difficult to give a precise answer, but my initial thoughts are that you have an issue with low temperature.

For cream to thicken you need to either a) Evaporate a lot of water from the cream itself or b) Use a thickening agent such as flour or cornflour. Both these approaches need higher temperatures than are generally achieved with your average Bain Marie (65 - 100C depending on the materials used), with cornflour thickening at 95C and flour at boiling point. While you will achieve some evaporation at lower temperatures, it will take forever.

Different materials have widely different efficiencies when used as double boilers. I'd check the temperature of your mixture, and maybe consider using a stainless steel bowl rather than glass, plastic, ceramic or Pyrex which will improve the heat conductivity a lot. Alternatively, you might need a different bowl / pan setup, as a bowl in a large saucepan (a long way from the simmering water) may not reach temperature.

If low temperature is crucial to your recipe, you could substitute gelatin as the thickening agent, that thickens down to 35C.